# rails 3 with a ajax created form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I want to create a page which user can modify data on that page.
So I tried to use a ajax call to replace the original data table row into a form.
The new form could be created and replace the row by my code currently. But after edited data in that form and click 'Update', nothing happened. In my console shows something like:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/projects/5"):
```

I can't figure out why it didn't work.

Codes are shown as following:

index.html.erb

```
<tr>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
</tr>

<% @projects.each do |project| %>
  <tr id="project_<%= project.id %>">
    <td><%= link_to project.name, project %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_project_path(project), :method => :get, :remote => true %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', project, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete , :remote => true %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

edit.js.erb

```
$('#project_<%= @project.id%>').replaceWith("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial=>'edit') %>");
```

_edit.html.erb

```
<tr id="project_<%= @project.id%>">
  <%= form_for(@project, :remote => true) do |f| %>
    <%= form_authenticity_token %>
    <td><%= f.text_field :name %></td>
    <td><%= f.submit 'Update' %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', @project, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete , :remote => true %></td>
  <% end %>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Routing errors are usually caused by one of the following:

1. you don't have the route specified in routes.rb.  Run "rake routes" at the command line and see if something like "/projects/:id" shows up.  If not you have to add the route by adding a projects resource or otherwise specifying the route manually.  Make sure the HTTP method matches the HTTP verb specified in routes.rb.
2. you have no controller named named ProjectsController or no create method (if your ajax method is posting) or no update method (if its putting).

Comment: Route exists but, yes, it's PUT. I used the same template, _edit.html.erb, to generate the same code in index.html.erb not using ajax. Every thing worked. I poped out the code ajax generated. It had a  hidden input data, _method = put. Is that ajax inserted code did not bind some js function that should be binded when page loaded? How do I fix it?